# How to determine lost connection with kqueue?

Tags: c, sockets, kqueue

I know that, here, on SO, are many questions themed like this. I've read through most of the similar questions and can not find an answer for my case.

I use `kqueue` for server/client socket echo application. The program uses exclusively BSD socket API. The program is work in progress. Now I am at the point of getting `EOF` from socket.

My setup follows.

1. Start server, that waits for connections, and accepts one socket.
2. Start client that connects.
3. No user data sent by this time. Close the client with `SIGINT`.
4. Server `kqueue` gets `EOF` flag with no errors.
5. `read` system call returns `zero` with no errors.

The problem is that I get no indication that connection was fully closed. I can not determine if I have to `shutdown` read end, or completely close a socket. I get no indication of `EOF` with the write end. And that is expected, since I did not register for the write event(no data were sent by now).

How to properly tell, if the socket was fully closed?

**Update**

I know that what follows may belong to other post. I think that this update is tightly connected with the question, and the question will benefit as a whole.

To the point. Since I get a read `EOF`, but not a write `EOF`(the socket is closed before any data comes in, or out), can I somehow query socket for its state?

What I learned from other network related questions, here, on SO, that network stack may get some packets on a socket. Like `FIN`, or `RST`. It will be a sure win for me to just get the socket state, in the particular case.

As a second option, will it help to add one-time write event **after** I got a read `EOF`, just to get a write `EOF`? Will the write `EOF` event trigger?

I know I will get write error eventually. But, until that time, the socket will be a dead weight.

It will be of a great convenience to `getsockopt` for the write end close. Or, at least, queuing an event for read endpoint shutdown, after the read returned `EOF`.

I did not found similar `getsockopt` options, and I am not sure about queue'ing write event. The source code for `kevent`, and a network stack in general, is too tough for me.
That is why I ask.

Comment: If `read` returns `0`, you should generally always (fully) close your end of the connection.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I manually call `shutdown`. The situation when one end can still send or receive is definitely possible with my design. Without some major recap and redesign of my methodology, I do not know how can I just close socket right away.

Comment: Then look at it like this: If `read` (or `recv`) returns `0`, you should look at it like: There's nothing more to read, you can close for reading/receiving.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OK

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can you please post an answer to the question? The people who use the review queue will eventually find the question and will spend time to answer it. Revisiting the TCP documentation, I've found that it is only sane way to close on `read 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `read` or `recv` returns `0` then that means the other end closed the connection. It's at least a half-close for writing (from the other peer), which means there's nothing more to be received from that connection.

Unless the protocol specifies that it's only a half-close and that you can continue to send data, it's generally best to simply do a full closing of the connection from your side.

Comment: the second paragraph is what I think of right now. In general, it is not possible to determine full close in all and any case.